# step function to get the task status when step execution is completed

Tags: python, aws-lambda, devops, aws-cli

I have tried to modify this python script to get the result of the step function execution , but is failing with :

```
File "step_function.py", line 6, in <module>
    input = json.dumps({})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the StartExecution operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

The code I used in the python script is :

```
 import time
  from time import sleep
  import boto3
    import json
    sf_client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
    sf_output = sf_client.start_execution(
        stateMachineArn = arn:aws:states:us-west-2:208244xxxxx:stateMachine:samplePipelinedevs-xxxxx,
        input = json.dumps({})
    )
    
    while True:
        time.sleep(5) # don't need to check every nanosecond
    
        sf_response = sf_client.describe_execution(executionArn=sf_output['executionArn'])
        status = sf_response['status'] # BE SURE TO GET THE CURRENT STATE
    
        print("%s: %s" % ("> Status...", status))
    
        if status == 'RUNNING':
            continue
        elif status == 'FAILED':
            raise Exception("%s: %s" % ("! ERROR ! Execution FAILED: ", sf_response))
        else: # SUCCEEDED
            break
```

Comment: Do you have the authentication configured  ? Usually the client needs explicit configuration like `client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN
)` unless you configured it in a system level.

Comment: @kris. I configured it on aws configure credentials file

Comment: @kris is working now but I do not want to put the ACCESS_KEY in the pythn it should be stored in the aws configure strange though

Comment: How have you configured the aws config file ?

Comment: It is configured manually using "aws configure --profile devsample"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the AWS Documentation, if you created a credential with `AWS CLI` and with a profile name, then you need to configure your client with that profile. For this you can use the session with profile name. Example below (w.r.t your code).

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='devsample')
sf_client = session.client('stepfunctions')
.
.
```

Boto has to know, which profile and credential to use, which you can specify with `Session`. Refer to the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/guide/configuration.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Kris. It is okay to use this temporary.